# WPF DataGrid - clicking a button in a cell with the keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to use a DataGrid where some of the columns need to be clickable commands. I will probably style them like hyperlinks, so I could use a DataGridTemplateColumn with a button or a DataGridHyperlinkColumn.

However, the users of the end product expect to be able to use a keyboard as an alternative to picking up the mouse.

So, the user can use the arrow keys to navigate to the cell in question and then the obvious thing is to press 'Enter'.  If I don't trap the Enter key in a subclass's OnPreviewKeyDown, the DataGrid moves to the next row.  But once I have it captured, how do I cause it to have the same effect as clicking on the cell contents?

Comment: Bind both events to the same `Command`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the properties of the KeyboardNavigation class in the XAML template for the grid cell contents, e.g:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
          KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" />
```

There are multiple properties which can help you configure keyboard navigation.

Comment: I just tried setting KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="True" on a button element within a DataGridTemplateColumn and it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: and di you try the other properties?